# how to wait until data is added in the block in multichain?

Tags: node.js, blockchain

I am trying to add a data in a stream via the following code.

```
mc.publish({ stream: "datastream", key: "through", data: packet }).then(x => {
    sucess++;
    //total_size += passedSize;
    callback(null, sucess);

}).catch(y => {
    //sucess++;
    //total_size += passedSize;
    callback(null, sucess);
})
```

This code returns callback when data is added in the unspent pool but I want to wait until it's added in the block.

Here are the parameters that I have used.

```
chain-protocol = multichain             # Chain protocol: multichain (permissions, native assets) or bitcoin
chain-description = MultiChain buchain  # Chain description, embedded in genesis block coinbase, max 90 chars.
root-stream-name = root                 # Root stream name, blank means no root stream.
root-stream-open = true                 # Allow anyone to publish in root stream
chain-is-testnet = false                # Content of the 'testnet' field of API responses, for compatibility.
target-block-time = 2                   # Target time between blocks (transaction confirmation delay), seconds. (2 - 86400)
maximum-block-size = 1000000000         # Maximum block size in bytes. (1000 - 1000000000)

# Global permissions

anyone-can-connect = false              # Anyone can connect, i.e. a publicly readable blockchain.
anyone-can-send = false                 # Anyone can send, i.e. transaction signing not restricted by address.
anyone-can-receive = false              # Anyone can receive, i.e. transaction outputs not restricted by address.
anyone-can-receive-empty = true         # Anyone can receive empty output, i.e. without permission grants, asset transfers and zero native currency.
anyone-can-create = false               # Anyone can create new streams.
anyone-can-issue = false                # Anyone can issue new native assets.
anyone-can-mine = false                 # Anyone can mine blocks (confirm transactions).
anyone-can-activate = false             # Anyone can grant or revoke connect, send and receive permissions.
anyone-can-admin = false                # Anyone can grant or revoke all permissions.
support-miner-precheck = true           # Require special metadata output with cached scriptPubKey for input, to support advanced miner checks.
allow-arbitrary-outputs = false         # Allow arbitrary (without clear destination) scripts.
allow-p2sh-outputs = true               # Allow pay-to-scripthash (P2SH) scripts, often used for multisig. Ignored if allow-arbitrary-outputs=true.
allow-multisig-outputs = true           # Allow bare multisignature scripts, rarely used but still supported. Ignored if allow-arbitrary-outputs=true.

# Consensus requirements

setup-first-blocks = 60                 # Length of initial setup phase in blocks, in which mining-diversity,
                                        # admin-consensus-* and mining-requires-peers are not applied. (1 - 31536000)
mining-diversity = 0.3                  # Miners must wait <mining-diversity>*<active miners> between blocks. (0 - 1)
admin-consensus-upgrade = 0.5           # <admin-consensus-upgrade>*<active admins> needed to upgrade the chain. (0 - 1)
admin-consensus-admin = 0.5             # <admin-consensus-admin>*<active admins> needed to change admin perms. (0 - 1)
admin-consensus-activate = 0.5          # <admin-consensus-activate>*<active admins> to change activate perms. (0 - 1)
admin-consensus-mine = 0.5              # <admin-consensus-mine>*<active admins> to change mining permissions. (0 - 1)
admin-consensus-create = 0.0            # <admin-consensus-create>*<active admins> to change create permissions. (0 - 1)
admin-consensus-issue = 0.0             # <admin-consensus-issue>*<active admins> to change issue permissions. (0 - 1)

# Defaults for node runtime parameters

lock-admin-mine-rounds = 10             # Ignore forks that reverse changes in admin or mine permissions after this many mining rounds have passed. Integer only. (0 - 10000)
mining-requires-peers = true            # Nodes only mine blocks if connected to other nodes (ignored if only one permitted miner).
mine-empty-rounds = 10                  # Mine this many rounds of empty blocks before pausing to wait for new transactions. If negative, continue indefinitely (ignored if target-adjust-freq>0). Non-integer allowed. (-1 - 1000)
mining-turnover = 0.5                   # Prefer pure round robin between a subset of active miners to minimize forks (0.0) or random equal participation for all permitted miners (1.0). (0 - 1)

# Native blockchain currency (likely not required)

initial-block-reward = 0                # Initial block mining reward in raw native currency units. (0 - 1000000000000000000)
first-block-reward = -1                 # Different mining reward for first block only, ignored if negative. (-1 - 1000000000000000000)
reward-halving-interval = 52560000      # Interval for halving of mining rewards, in blocks. (60 - 1000000000)
reward-spendable-delay = 1              # Delay before mining reward can be spent, in blocks. (1 - 100000)
minimum-per-output = 0                  # Minimum native currency per output (anti-dust), in raw units.
                                        # If set to -1, this is calculated from minimum-relay-fee. (-1 - 1000000000)
maximum-per-output = 100000000000000    # Maximum native currency per output, in raw units. (0 - 1000000000000000000)
minimum-relay-fee = 0                   # Minimum transaction fee, per 1000 bytes, in raw units of native currency. (0 - 1000000000)
native-currency-multiple = 100000000    # Number of raw units of native currency per display unit. (0 - 1000000000)

# Advanced mining parameters

skip-pow-check = false                  # Skip checking whether block hashes demonstrate proof of work.
pow-minimum-bits = 1                    # Initial and minimum proof of work difficulty, in leading zero bits. (1 - 32)
target-adjust-freq = -1                 # Interval between proof of work difficulty adjustments, in seconds, if negative - never adjusted. (-1 - 4294967295)
allow-min-difficulty-blocks = false     # Allow lower difficulty blocks if none after 2*<target-block-time>.

# Standard transaction definitions

only-accept-std-txs = true              # Only accept and relay transactions which qualify as 'standard'.
max-std-tx-size = 100000000             # Maximum size of standard transactions, in bytes. (1024 - 100000000)
max-std-op-returns-count = 1024         # Maximum number of OP_RETURN metadata outputs in standard transactions. (0 - 1024)
max-std-op-return-size = 2097152        # Maximum size of OP_RETURN metadata in standard transactions, in bytes. (0 - 67108864)
max-std-op-drops-count = 5              # Maximum number of OP_DROPs per output in standard transactions. (0 - 100)
max-std-element-size = 32768            # Maximum size of data elements in standard transactions, in bytes. (128 - 32768)
```

How to do that multichain? any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `publish` function returns a `txid`
You could later query your `stream` by `txid` using `getstreamitem`

Then your code would look something like this:

```
mc.publish({ stream: "datastream", key: "through", data: packet }).then(txId => {
    checking = true
    while(checking) {
        mc.getstreamitem({ stream: "datastream", txid: txId}).then(res => {
            checking = false
            sucess++;
            //total_size += passedSize;
            callback(null, sucess);
        }).catch(err => {
            checking = false
            callback(err, sucess);
        })
        // you can delay here or something
    }
}).catch(y => {
    //sucess++;
    //total_size += passedSize;
    callback(null, sucess);
})
```

You can replace the while with some other polling mechanism. I've just written an adhoc version here.

PS: I have no experience with `multichain` specifically. It's my first time seeing their documentation. The documentation looks rather inconvenient to me.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Thanks for giving too much effort. Sorry for the inconvenience. Actually, they read local copy for `getstreamitem`. It doesn't matter it's added in the network or not.

Comment: i believe you can still poll or continuously query the local copy until it gives you something with the given `txid`

Comment: sure, i will give a try and let you now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your data calculate result will return to `packet` right ?
If so you must bring that data packet in the promise or async await 
=> when you wrote data in `promise` or `async await` they will wait until data processing completed and then they will do `mc.publish({...`

You can read more about promise [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and async await [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Remember Async await just a newer function than promise function. so you can use either of these

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. in multichain, there are two phases. One is added in the transaction pool and after that, add the data in the block. Now, I am getting time for transaction pool but I want to wait till the block is added.